# OpenGL - Question about the usage of glDepthMask

Tags: opengl

I have rendered an objectA in a scene as follows. The scene has many other objects too.

```
void Draw()
{    
    if( glIsList( displayListID ) )
    {
        glPushAttrib( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_ENABLE_BIT );

        glEnable( GL_BLEND );
        glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
        //glDepthMask( GL_FALSE );
        glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

        glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH );
        glEnable( GL_POINT_SMOOTH );
        glEnable( GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH );

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW ); 

        color.setAlpha(alpha); // set alpha transparent of this objectA
        glCallList( displayListID );

        //glDepthMask( GL_TRUE );
        glDisable( GL_BLEND );  

        glPopAttrib();
    }
}
```

Now here is the problem,

As shown, I comment out two lines
//glDepthMask( GL_FALSE );
//glDepthMask( GL_TRUE );

the scene renders the objectA and other objects correctly in depth. However,
the modification of the objectA alpha doesn't work anymore (i.e. color.setAlpha(alpha) ).

If I uncomment the above two lines, then alpha modification is back to work. However, the depth rendering is NOT correct. In other words, sometimes, the objectA should be behind other objects but it looks like the objectA is in front of all objects.

How do I fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 73, accepted):

1. Turn **on** the depth mask `glDepthMask( GL_TRUE )`
2. Draw all opaque objects, in any order
3. Turn off the depth mask `glDepthMask( GL_FALSE )`
4. Turn on a `BLEND_MODE`
5. Draw translucent objects sorted from *furthest away* to *nearest*

Why do you do this?

There are 2 buffers you need to worry about: the **depth buffer** and the **color buffer**.  These buffers are really just big 2d arrays, each the width x height of your screen.

The **color buffer** naturally is going to hold the final coloration of each pixel.  There is one entry in the color buffer per screen pixel.  The **depth buffer**, is like the color buffer in that there is one entry per screen pixel, but it is used for something different.  Entries in the *depth buffer* are a measure of "how close" each colored pixel really is.

If you render 1 triangle, that is far away from the camera, it generates a set of colors and depth values for each pixel it "wants" to cover on the screen. Say you then render another poly that is closer, it also will generate a set of values for the depth and color buffers.  Now, there is a sort of "contest" at pixel coloration time where the "further away" fragments (large depth buffer values) are discarded, and only the closest fragments are kept.  The closer fragments end up coloring the pixel you had.  (When two polygons are nearly overlapping, [Z-fighting can occur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting))

Start by rendering the objects in your scene with the depth mask on.  This means every shape you render, when its pixels get colored, the depth buffer gets updated with the "winner" of the contest.

Then, you 3) `glDepthMask( GL_FALSE )` turns **off** the depth buffer for writing, 4) turn on blending, 5) render translucent shapes from furthest to nearest.  Seems weird, huh?

When you turn off the depth mask, and render the translucent shapes, OpenGL will still *read* the depth buffer to determine which fragments to throw away (i.e. if your translucent shape is behind an already rendered solid shape, then you throw that translucent shape's fragments away).  But it **will not** write to the depth buffer, so if a translucent shape is really really close to the *eye* (say like a translucent windshield), **those windshield fragments do not prevent other fragments that are actually further away from being drawn**.  This is important, because if your windshield is right in front of you and you render it translucent, **and** you let the windshield fragments update the depth buffer then you will see nothing else in your scene except the windshield, even though there are shapes behind it, because OpenGL will think "Hey, that windshield is the only thing the user should see, due to these depth buffer readings, so I won't bother rendering anything further away than this windshield, then."  Turning off the depth mask is a way of "tricking" OpenGL into "not knowing" there are very close, but translucent, fragments.

Comment: Hello bobobobo,

It takes so much time for you to write such a detail description and it takes many counting for me to figure out how many bo repetition in your login name:)

Here is what I want to achieve.

In the scene, I have two objects, one (objectA) inside the other (ojectB). ObjectA is enclosed 3D sphere while objectB is a opened half sphere. ObjectA is sit right in the center of the objectB. If you rotate the view, you can see the relative position of objectA and objectB.

Now, the user can adjust alpha for objectA and objectB respectively. In other words, they can have different alpha

Comment: Based on your comments, I should always use glDepthMask( GL_FALSE ). But I must sort all triangles on the surf of the objectA and objectB so that the nearest one is rendered last.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you should sort the polygons in back-to-front order, so you lay down the color for the inner sphere first (without writing the depth buffer), and then you lay down the color of the outer sphere "on top" of it -- kind of like making a layered painting.  To sort the polygons from front to back, one algorithm to do it is use a BSP tree.  The BSP tree is a bit advanced, so what you can do is just __always render the inner sphere first__, since it will always be "behind" the outer sphere (unless you are _inside_ the inner sphere..).

Comment: +1 going through a project and having to implement transparency I found this very well explained.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed description bobobobo! People like you make Stackoverflow the best information source out there

Comment: Great explanation, but I realized that at least in some graphics cards I need to **enable** depth writes explicitly _before_ calling SwapBuffers, _even_ if I draw all opaque objects first and transparent objects later (setting the appropriate states every time). That is, it seems it's not enough to just enable depth writes again only when drawing the opaque scene at the beginning of the frame. I never understood why that is necessary. Any guess?

Comment: While writing the above comment and searching again on the problem, it hit me: actually the problem was that the depth write was off when glClear was called! It turns out depth writing is needed to clear the depth buffer (which does need to write on the buffer so I guess the behaviour makes some sense). This means you should at least set the depth write back to true at the beginning of the frame before you clear buffers.

Comment: I would like OpenGL documentation to explain things like @bobobobo

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution:  set `glDepthMask` to `GL_TRUE` at all times and draw all your non-transparent objects first (in any order, just as you seem to do it now), then draw all your (semi-)transparent objects sorted from back to front.

In some cases, if you don't care about the order in which your (semi-)transparent objects are drawn and you only want the other, opaque objects to "shine through", you can skip sorting your (semi-)transparent objects.

Comment: Basically you should sort your objects this way : 
- near opaque objects
- far opaque objects
- far transparent objects
- near transparent. 
Opaque first or your alpha blending won't work. Far transparent before near transparent for the same reason. And near opaque first because they are the most susceptible to fill the screen and spare fill-rate

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to turn of depth buffer writing, if you sort your translucent objects from back to front.
I render translucent objects like that:

1. Draw all opaque objects, in any order.
2. Turn on blending.
3. Draw translucent objects sorted from back to front.

The issue of discarding fragments mentioned by bobobobo arises when you have intersecting polygons. But in this case disabling the depth buffer won't produce a correct result in all cases. At first sight it might look right, but if you look carefully, you will notice incorrect blending order:

[Wrong blending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNlVK.jpg)

This case has mathematically no solution, since one polygon has to be rasterized before the other. 
To solve this issue you (or an artist) have to split the polygons at the intersection in a 3D editor (e.g. Blender). So you split your intersecting object into 2 or more and order them appropriately by your sorting algorithm.
Than the translucent parts will be rendered in correct order:

[Correct blending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Jma.jpg)

Note that depth buffer writing is enabled in the 2nd screenshot!

If you disable the depth buffer you would naturally get the same result, but you don't need it.
Indeed, it is easier to see such overlapping issues if the depth buffer writing is not disabled. This is the reason i prefer not to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Minor addition to other responses:

Even though visually it makes no difference what order you draw your opaque objects in, you should nevertheless sort them front-to-back to avoid over-draw and take advantage of the depth buffer to avoid pointless pixel shader invocations. This can have a significant performance impact. And even if sorting is slow, you can still bin your objects into near/medium/far groups and draw those in an explicit order.

For instance, in a 3D game, you always want to draw the sky last. Right before that, the landscape. Before that, distant objects. But start with the player or gun. The most stuff you draw first, that's closer, the less stuff you'll draw then overdraw. It's not always possible to do this with overlapping objects, but it's usually good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another simplified approach to get basic transparency effect without writing much code.
Mix and blend everything without objects sorting, without depth testing and without alpha interpolation, treating all objects' transparency equally.
Output pixel = 50% * source pixel + 50% * destination pixel

This may not provide high quality transparency and doesn't provide occlusion of far objects by close ones, but might be fast and have little impact on performance.

```
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE); // or glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
// r, g, b constant components are unused below, only constant 0.5f alpha
glBlendColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f); 
// set source and destination factors to 0.5f (50%) defined by above call
glBlendFunc(GL_CONSTANT_ALPHA, GL_CONSTANT_ALPHA);
```