# Transparent objects in OpenGl ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

So I've been playing around with OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android but now got to a problem I haven't been able to solve. Apologies in advance, it appears that I'm not allowed to post more that two links (yet), so I put my three images in a Photobucket album [here](http://s270.photobucket.com/user/mystyfly/library/StackOverflow?sort=9&page=1#).

I'm trying to create a 3D environment that is enclosed by transparent areas ("colored glass"). To see if it works I also put a opaque cube within. I enabled the following capabilities:

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Now the picture looks like this (screenshot 1). Not bad, but not exactly how I wanted it: A (lower) wall at the back as well as the wall on the right should be visible because the wall I'm looking through is transparent.

Then I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388294/opengl-question-about-the-usage-of-gldepthmask) and tried using `GLES20.glDepthMask(true);` before drawing the opaque and `GLES20.glDepthMask(false);` before drawing the transparent objects, as well as disabling blending while drawing the opaque objects.

The result (screenshot 2) looks quite messed up. But then I had another idea, not to turn off writing to the depth buffer but to turn off `GLES20.DEPTH_TEST` altogether, while drawing the transparent objects.

That (screenshot 3) got me closest tho the picture I'm looking for. You can finally see the backwall as well as the right sidewall but, because the depth testing is disabled when drawing the opaques, the cube is partially covered by the backwall, which it shouldn't be.

Does anyone know how to get the effect I'm looking for?

Comment: You are sort of on the right track here. At least you draw your opaque geometry and translucent geometry separately (and presumably, the opaque pass is done first). But you also need to sort your translucent geometry from back-to-front when you use this blend mode. You definitely want to keep the depth test enabled when you do your translucent pass, however, because opaque geometry should be allowed to occlude translucent geometry.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the opaque objects first. I've read about drawing back-to-front when using transparency (and front-to-back otherwise), however, I was hoping to avoid that because I would like to do move the camera (POV that is displayed on screen) around a lot and I don't know of a way to reliably detect which transparent object should be drawn when. You say "[...] when you use this blend mode.", does this mean there is another blend mode that might be better suited? I'm not familiar with the options that could be used with glBlendFunc(..). Why does using glDepthMask(..) have the effect it has?

Comment: 1. This is an order-dependent blend function, there are also additive blend functions that are order-independent... they will add the current fragment to the framebuffer instead of modulating based on the alpha component (almost certainly not what you want). 2. If you disable depth writes, then your translucent geometry does not update the depth buffer -- in other words it will not block additional layers of translucent geometry. This is why you need depth sorting, you need to make sure that there are no polygons with deeper depths that have not been drawn yet for alpha blending to work.

Comment: By the way, things get complicated if you have translucent polygons that intersect with each other. In this situation you have to draw at least one of the polygons twice. Order-dependence is not a pretty topic in computer graphics, and currently all of the solutions for order-independent transparency are quite complicated. Short of the SEGA Dreamcast, there is no commodity hardware/software that can simply be told: "blend this order independently".

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman +1 for explicitly stating that there is no independent blend order function. Pretty much everyone in the world of computer graphics should know this.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that I solved it. By that I mean that it works in my case but I can't tell if that is just by coincidence...

I am enabling depth testing and blending as usual. Then, when drawing, I draw the opaque shapes first and the transparent shapes second, like before. But, while drawing the transparent shapes, I turn `GLES20.glDepthMask(..)` off to not write to the depth buffer and thus draw all transparent shapes that are not covered by opaque shapes. I did that previously (picture 2) and it completely messed up but I now I do it in reverse - disabling the depth mask for transparent shapes, not opaque ones.